# Merging back new calculations in original pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Pandas dataframe named 'df' and seen below:

```
   X   Y  Z
0 -3   6 -7
1 -4 -10 -1
2  9 -10 -9
3  5   0 -8
4 -2   1 -8
```

And I want to create a new frame out of some of the rows in df:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df['X'] == -3) & (df['X'] == 9)]
```

And then I modify the new data frame:

```
new_df.Y = 150
```

Is there an easy way to insert my new data frame back into the old frame, replacing only those values that I modified in the new frame?

So in the end, I would have the original 'df' and it would look like this:

```
   X   Y  Z
0 -3  150 -7
1 -4 -10 -1
2  9 -150 -9
3  5   0 -8
4 -2   1 -8
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace values with conditions, you can do it in one step, i.e. specify the row and column conditions and assign values, and you can avoid merging the new data frame with the original data frame:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] == -3) | (df['X'] == 9), "Y"] = 150  
# I assume you mean or instead of and from your result

df
#    X    Y  Z
#0  -3  150 -7
#1  -4  -10 -1
#2   9  150 -9
#3   5    0 -8
#4  -2    1 -8
```

As long as the index of the `new_df` is not modified, you can assign the `new_df.Y` back to df after modification has been made to `new_df`:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] == -3) | (df['X'] == 9), "Y"] = new_df.Y
```

Or even:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] == -3) | (df['X'] == 9)] = new_df
```

Comment: Thank you, but after I create the new frame, I want to run a linear regression using all the X and Y values in the new frame. I am not sure if I can do that with the solution you have posted. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think I get your idea. Why can't you run linear regression with X and Y with this data frame?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running linear regression on this df

Comment: Because I do not want certain values of X and Y included in the linear regression, hence the reason why I am creating a new frame with only those values of X with which I want to be included in the df.

Comment: Is `Y` column the only column that gets modified? What happens to Z?

Comment: X and Z will be used to predict Y. They will not change.